# Can i show multiple option on selection of a word in web Browser control of windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control, highlighting, textselection

How can i show multiple option on selection of a word in web Browser control of windows phone 8 ? I am showing images which is default behavior of web Browser control of windows phone 8

[image: The default feature of windows phone 8's web browser control on selection a word or line.]

**I want the following look after the selection in web browser control of windows phone 8. Is It possible or possible than how can i implement ?**

[image: I want following multiple options icons on selection a word or line in windows phone 8's web browser control.]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify this appearance as it is standard OS behavior. There is no way to access or change it.